# Where do I learn about jewel bearings?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, bearings, friction, research

I would like to take a deep dive into the world of jewel sourced watchmaking components (including, but not limited to, bearings) but I am having trouble finding any textbooks on the subject. Are there any watchmakers/horologists/jewelers who can kindly point me in the right direction?

This all started when I decided to design a very tiny rolling scotch-yoke mechanism & thus required an equally tiny bearing. Here is a figure showing a regular & rolling scoth-yoke on the left & right, resp.

[image: scotch-yoke mechanism]

The only jewel bearings I have found are optimized to be fixed externally s.t. an internal pivot can freely rotate within its bore. I want to know if there are any other jewel sourced components optimized for my immediate use, or any other future uses I might have.

Comment: A quick google search gives: https://www.watchonista.com/articles/opinions/our-top-10-must-read-watchmaking-books and https://www.esslinger.com/books-publications-2/

Comment: This is why watchmakers are also jewellers.